# PostGIS query to Select all Polygons from Polygon table having an intersecting geometry with one or more point in passed list of GeoCoordinates

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have a polygons table in Postgres (using PostGIS extension) named polygon having two fields (geom, id).

If I want to query the id of the polygon which intersects with the geometry of input geo-coordinate then I can do it with the below query.

```
SELECT id, geom 
FROM polygon 
WHERE ST_Intersects(polygon.%s, ST_GeometryFromText(POINT(latitude logitude), 4326));
```

But now I have a use case where I am getting a lot of geo-coordinates in request(~60k), now I am breaking this into lists of 1k Geo-coordinate each and querying the id of the polygon intersecting with each geo-coordinate.

I am struggling with how to write. a query for this, or if anyone has a better solution for this please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep in mind that the right order of coordinate pairs is `lon, lat`, so creating a point with `lat, lon` in your query will return wrong results. Your query also misses the single quotes `'` around the WKT coordinate, e.g. `'POINT(1 2)'`.

That all being said, you could simply paginate your result sets using `ORDER BY`, `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`, e.g.

Getting the first 1000 records

```
SELECT id, geom FROM polygon
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, 'SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)')
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 0;
```

By changing the `OFFSET` value you are able to retrieve the next pages.

```
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000;
```

and so on ..

```
LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 2000;
```

**EDIT**: One way to apply this query using multiple input points is to use a [`CTE / subquery`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) (see comments), e.g.

```
WITH j(g) AS (
  VALUES 
    ('SRID=4326;POINT(1 1)'),
    ('SRID=4326;POINT(1 2)') 
    -- ... add as many geometries as you want
)
SELECT id, geom FROM polygon, j
WHERE ST_Intersects(geom, g::geometry)
```

Comment: I have the list of lat, lon(List<GeoCoordinate>) in my application code, how to invoke the query using the list, and make sure the query takes each point from list one by one. like pass the list from application to DB, DB then takes each point one by one from the list and finds. the id of the polygons intersecting for each corresponding point.

Comment: Is possible to put this query into a loop in your application, so that you can run the query using every point one by one? Or you need to do it in one single query?

Comment: I am looking for a way to run at once(in batched of 1-2K) so that as I have 60k geocoordinates to query

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal I just added a `CTE` to my amswer. Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: if there are many geometries in input, does the Postgres server itself executes the queries parallelly for better performance or we need to specify that?

Comment: well, this is a totally different question. Depending on your PosgreSQL, the server splits the query into parallel processes automatically. Does the query work?

Comment: Yes the query does works but just exploring a way I can just pass the list<geocoordinate> to Postgres and it can loop it.

Comment: @ShubhamGoyal consider inserting this points into a table and execute the query referencing to it. Considering this amount of data I would definitely do it ;)